# Get Fragment Manager from Custom Component

Tags: android, listener, custom-component

I need to open a dialog from my custom component. To do this I need fragment manager, but I can't call getFragmentManager():
"The method getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Context"

```
public class MyCustomButton extends Button {

    View.OnClickListener myOnlyhandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyDialogFragment dialog = new MyDialogFragment();
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Tag");
        }
    };

}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

The buttons are placed in layout file:

```
<com.example.MyCustomButton android:id="@+id/myId1"/>
<com.example.MyCustomButton android:id="@+id/myId2"/>
<com.example.MyCustomButton android:id="@+id/myId3"/>
```

I need one listener for all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to create buttons programmatically and pass the context to the declared class like this.
change your class to this:

```
public class MyCustomButton extends Button {
private Context context;
View.OnClickListener myOnlyhandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        MyDialogFragment dialog = new MyDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Tag");
    }
};
public void MyCustomButton(Context context){
   this.context=context;
   }
}
```

and then declare your button like this:

```
MyCustomButton button = new MyCustomButton(MainActivity.this);
```

then you have to add this view to main `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a context into the constructor and then cast with an Activity or FragmentActivity to be able to get the FragmentManager or SupportFragmentManger:

```
public class MyCustomButton extends Button implements View.OnClickListener {

     private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

     public void MyCustomButton(Context context){
        fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) context).getFragmentManager();
        setOnClickListener(this);
     }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        MyDialogFragment dialog = new MyDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(fragmentManager, "Tag");
    }
}
```